# Convert a list of matrices to a dataframe of vectors.

Tags: r

I have a list of matrices with row and column names.

```
matrix.list <-lapply(1:3, function(x) matrix(rnorm(6, 10, 1), nrow=3, ncol=3,dimnames = list(c('a','b','c'),c('a','b','c'))))
```

The matrices also have names.

```
names(matrix.list) <- c('cool','pizza','taco')
```

I want this list to become a data frame of each matrix as a vector. It is not important to preserve the row or column names. Furthermore, I want the name of each vector in the data frame to be the name of the matrix within the list of matrices. Here is a way to do that which requires entering in the position of every single matrix within the list that I want to go into the data frame:

```
data <- data.frame(as.vector(matrix.list[[1]]), as.vector(matrix.list[[2]]), as.vector(matrix.list[[3]]))
colnames(data) <- names(matrix.list)

data
       cool     pizza      taco
1 10.039986 10.186506 11.765118
2 10.218540  9.881437 10.940238
3  9.991317  8.768257 11.056617
4  9.454922  9.726288  8.786040
5  9.799430  9.730105  8.495879
6  9.491335 11.836056  9.825230
7 10.039986 10.186506 11.765118
8 10.218540  9.881437 10.940238
9  9.991317  8.768257 11.056617
```

How do I do this better?

Comment: `as.data.frame(lapply(matrix.list, c))` or `as.vector` in place of `c`... not sure if it matters which.

Comment: @Frank this is the answer!

Comment: Cool, glad it worked. I'm thinking there must be a dupe of this around somewhere (in the sense of introducing `as.data.frame(List_of_vectors)`), so I won't post it as an answer for now.